# Errors occurred during the build in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to Eclipse. I am facing one error whenever I am creating any project or package.

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'Hello'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Also on running a small "Hello world program " in java
Here is my program:

```
public class MyHello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.print("Hello World");
    }

}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module Hello not found
```

Here is my java version:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
java version "12" 2019-03-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 12+33)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 12+33, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I am using latest Eclipse version 2019-03

```
Project: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
```

Comment: Without posting your code there's nothing we can to help you. See -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What kind of project did you make? What JDK is installed in Eclipse? And which Eclipse version are you using?

Comment: @mayamar, I have updated the post

Comment: @Dymas, I have updated the post with code

Comment: For Java 12 the [_Java 12 Support for Eclipse 2019-03 (4.11)_ plug-in](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-12-support-eclipse-2019-03-411) is required.

Comment: your module setup of module 'Hello" might be flawed or non existent.

Comment: @howlger, Thanks it works!! I could not see any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Java 12 the [*Java 12 Support for Eclipse 2019-03 (4.11)* plug-in](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-12-support-eclipse-2019-03-411) is required.